# Using silent push notifications to keep an iOS app in "Background" state

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Is it possible to keep an iOS app in "Background" state by sending it a silent push notification every few seconds? I want to run background tasks on a regular interval and this seems like a viable solution. If so, is this acceptable under the App Store terms of use?

The app I am planning to build would rely on this functionality and I am concerned that Apple will reject it from the App Store.

Specifically, it’s this section in the [guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html#push-notifications) that I am not sure about:

> 5.1 Apps that send Push Notifications without first obtaining user consent, **as well as apps that require Push Notifications to function, will be rejected**

Technically my app could be used without allowing push notifications but it wouldn’t serve its primary function of recording data in the background.

Answer (score 3):

In iOS7 additional background modes were added, you can check out the available background modes [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3).
IMHO, if you misuse one of the background modes, the app will probably be rejected, saying that , i don't think silent push notifications were meant for: `keep an iOS app in "Background" state by sending it a silent push notification every few seconds`.

another thing is that silent push notifications are rate limited as described [here](http://asciiwwdc.com/2013/sessions/204?q=push%20notification), so i'm not sure if they will be sent every few seconds.

maybe you can use another background service

Comment: Great info, thanks. I had no idea about the rate limit; that’s probably a deal-breaker.

Answer (score 1):

This is only possible via Cydia. Which means you will need to have a Repository, and jailbroken device for this to work.

The App Store will surely reject this, as it forces other apps to work in the background.

Comment: Performing tasks in the background is allowed. See [“Multitasking Enhancements”](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS7.html) 

The question is whether Apple will reject an app form the App Store if it depends on silent push notification in order to perform its primary function.

Comment: of course performing tasks in the background is allowed. And the "Multitasking Enhancements" in the link you gave only was for the creators own app. For Example, facebook can keep ITSELF on in the background. and it does not mean facebook can force other apps that are not backgrounding on the background.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. I’m not trying to force other apps into “Background” state – just my own.

Comment: oh, then you can. sorry, i misunderstood. it would work.