# Silent Push Notifications To Avoid App Getting In Suspended State

Tags: ios, background, notifications, location, silent

I'm working on an app that fetches background location from users to provide relevant content to them when they are in proximity of a defined set of points of interest.

By testing my app I see that once the app goes in Background state, it is eventually moved to a Suspended state by the system, [as reported by the Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW3). I know that apps that are not used by the user will eventually get suspended, but there should be ways to extend their life before the get suspended. I found some older discussions about this topic:

[Prevent my application from being suspended in background mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15663757/prevent-my-application-from-being-suspended-in-background-mode)

[Silent push notifications only delivered if device is charging and/or app is foreground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26959472/silent-push-notifications-only-delivered-if-device-is-charging-and-or-app-is-for)

Specifically, I'm wondering what can be accomplished using silent push notifications and what other options are available.

Has anyone tried to solve this issue with the latest iOS 10? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24742490/558933

Comment: Thanks for the link, I checked it but I think that my use case is different. The app already uses background modes and it doesn't "need silent push notifications every few seconds". Also, the topic is from 2014 and iOS 7, I'm trying to build some knowledge about the state of the art with iOS10.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is NO.

Silent notifications wakes your app in the background as apple docs say. It is not meant to keep your app always in background, in fact silent notifications are very limited:

> The system treats silent notifications as low-priority. You can use
>   them to refresh your app’s content, but the system doesn't guarantee
>   their delivery. In addition, the delivery of silent notifications may
>   be throttled if the total number becomes excessive. The actual number
>   of silent notifications allowed by the system depends on current
>   conditions, **but don't try to send more than two or three silent
>   notifications per hour**.

There is no way to prevent your app get suspended unless you use music, maps or other unrelated features. And if you try to be smart and circumvent Apple policies by abusing app capabilities provided (PushKIT, HealthKIT etc), then you app most likely will get rejected.

Comment: what happen if get any event/notification in suspended state?

Comment: Your app is awakened to be in background state and the predefined methods get called. Your app will stay in background for a limited time.